# Adding Gesture to TableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a swipe gesture recognizer to a tableViewCell but it doesn't work.

This is the way I create my cell:

```
CellIdentifier = @"EventsSentCell";
    nibObjcet = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EventsSentCell" owner:self options:nil];

EventsSentCell *cell = [[EventsSentCell alloc] init];
cell = (EventsSentCell *)[nibObjcet objectAtIndex:0];
```

and this is how my cell is initiated in the .m file:

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
        leftSwipe.direction= UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [leftSwipe addTarget:self action:@selector(swipedLeft)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and this is how I declared my gesture recognizer in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe;
```

But for some reason my method isn't called.

Any ideas?

Thanks

I've tried putting the below code:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    NSLog(@"%@",gestureRecognizer);
    return YES;
}
```

and the result i'm getting after swiping left is:

```
<UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0xa9d99a0; state = Possible; view = <UITableViewCellContentView 0xa9d8ce0>; target= <(action=_longPressGestureRecognized:, target=<EventsSentCell 0xa9d8bb0>)>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the actual question, let  me point out some other issues in your code.

```
EventsSentCell *cell = [[EventsSentCell alloc] init];
cell = (EventsSentCell *)[nibObjcet objectAtIndex:0];
```

First of all, there's no point in these two lines. You're allocating and initializing an instance of `EventSentCell` without a nib. After doing this you're overwriting `cell` to point to the instance initialized by `loadNibNamed:`. You could simplify this to `EventsSentCell = (EventsSentCell *)nibObject[0];`
But even after these optimizations, this still isn't the recommended way to implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in `viewDidLoad` and then use 
`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` to get a cell and leave out loading the nib yourself completely.

Next,

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe;
```

You declare this property as an `IBOutlet` but you're setting it (as far as I know) only in code, more specifically the `init` method. You could just leave out the `IBOutlet` altogether.

And this `init` method is probably also the cause of your problem. When instantiating a view using `loadNibNamed`, `initWithCoder:` is called instead of `init`. Implement your custom initialization code (adding a gesture recognizer in this case) there and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'init' method is not getting called, so the gesture recognizer does not get set up.

You could try initialising in `awakeFromNib` instead, but anyway your cell creation looks unconventional.

Assuming you are using a custom cell class with a Xib file, here is how I would do it.

1. Create your `EventsSentCell` object .m and .h files
2. Create a xib file "EventsSentCell.xib"
3. In the xib file, delete the default top-level view and replace it with a UITableViewCell (you can drag one out from the objects library). In the identity inspector change it's class to `EventsSentCell`
4. In you table viewController's `viewDidLoad`...

   ```
    UINib* EventsSentNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"EventsSentCell" 
                                          bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:EventsSentNib 
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"EventsSentCell"];
   ```
5. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = 
          [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventsSentCell"];
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                           initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
                         reuseIdentifier:@"EventsSentCell"];
     }
   ```
6. In EventsSentCell.m, trigger your initialisation code from `-awakeFromNib`

Your initialisation code:

```
    leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    leftSwipe.direction= UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [leftSwipe addTarget:self action:@selector(swipedLeft)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];
```

will work as it is.

You get the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer:...` response to your gestureRecogniser delegate method because that is a built-in gesture recognizer provided by Apple that has it's delegate set to the cell. When your code is working correctly, if you also set *your* gesture recongnizer's delegate to the cell (`leftSwipe.delegate = self`), you would expect to see a simlilar log for `UISwipeGestureRecognizer:...`

It is also noting that the UILongPressGestureRecognizer's view is NOT the cell, but the cell's `contentView`. This is the superview for your cell's view hierarchy, to which you should attach all of your cell's content. Although your gesture recognizer works when you attach it to the cell, I would advise following Apple here:

```
        [self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];
```

Then the gesture will correctly follow the cell's view hierarchy.